# How to change url_alias partially according to a pattern Drupal

Tags: drupal

How to change url_alias partially according to a pattern?

We have site with reports to users.
We continue to update the reports with new content node but the url_alias kept same.
For example, 
    /report/report_a
    /report/report_a/subreport_1
    /report/report_b
…...
Users bookmark the pages. So they can get into the reports directly.

Recently we change the path pattern with /docs/ in front:
    /docs/report/report_a
    /docs/report/report_a/subreport_1
    /docs/report/report_b
…...
Now the new content nodes go to these url_alias.

But the users have booked mark the pages.
So we want to make them previous book marks, url_alias, can be redirected into the new path.
For example, 
    /report/report_a to be redirected into /docs/report/report_a
    /report/report_a/subreport_1 to be redirected into
    /docs/report/report_a/subreport_1

That means to make /report/* paths to be redirectly to /docs/report/* paths
Here * is wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Do the old report pages still exist? You could add a bit of javascript to each page that redirects to the new location...

Comment: The old report pages are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create aliases for the old nodes? If there are a lot, it probably wouldn't be too hard to run a script that takes all the old paths and creates aliases for them.

In D7, URL Aliases are under Config | Search and metadata

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest add a redirect to your .htaccess file. Something like this should work for your example:

> Redirect /report/ /docs/report/